# How do I avoid thoughts of zina & concentrate on my salah and studies?

Tags: nikah, islamic-philosophy, sawm, zina

I'm a 20+ year old male. From the past two to three years, I have been facing a terrible problem within my mind. My mind always fill with bad thoughts like zina.
 Sometimes those thought came with family women.

I am not a bad person and just want to come out of this situation. Sometimes I just want to kill myself if couldn't find any other way. I am also unable to do my prayer or study well.

Please advice.

Comment: Advice-requests are hardly on topic. You are free to rephrase your inquiry (see [ask], [ask!](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [don't ask!](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)).

Answer (score 3):

You may seem being experiencing the effects of hormonal changes if you haven't already in your early teens. Nonetheless, please refer to the below Hadith

> Narrated `Abdullah:
>
> We were with the Prophet (ﷺ) while we were young and had no wealth
>   whatever. So Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "O young people! **Whoever
>   among you can marry, should marry**, because it helps him lower his
>   gaze and guard his modesty (i.e. his private parts from committing
>   illegal sexual intercourse etc.), and **whoever is not able to marry,
>   should fast**, as fasting diminishes his sexual power."
>   [Sahih al-Bukhari 5066](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/67/4)

The Prophet(ﷺ) gave clear instructions that after reaching puberty, if one is able to marry (is both emotionally and financially capable to supporting a family) then he should go ahead and marry.

Alternately, he should keep fasts as it reduces his strength and guards his spirit. I have come across a few young people in the west who are exposed to a lot of fitna and choose to fast atleast twice a week. This helps them follow the sunnah and also guard their imaan.

I'd also recommend you to surround yourself with good friends who are good at studies and stay away from vices. Both bad company and staying alone helps shaytan gain control over desires whereas good company helps us not get distracted.

Best of luck and may Allah make it easy for you.

Comment: To add, I would just try to make sure that I'm not fasting beyond what my body can bear. See hadith [Sahih Bukhari Vol 3, Book 31, 196](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/82)